# Como traduzir "uphill battle"?

Tags: tradução, palavra-para-ideia, expressões-idiomáticas

Google Tradutor diz que poderia ser "batalha difícil", mas isso não dá o mesmo efeito da expressão original. Existe alguma forma melhor de traduzir isso?

Comment: Bem-vindo Luiz Pontes. Podes explicar o sentido de _uphill battle_ para aqueles não familiarizados com o termo? Certamente ajudaria a obter boas respostas!

Comment: Uma frase de exemplo também ajudaria.

Comment: uma batalha de sísifo.

Comment: Não, @Lambie, uma tarefa de Sísifo seria infinita e sem chance nenhuma de sucesso; uma "_uphill battle_" é uma batalha com constantes dificuldades, mas com alguma chance de sucesso. Cf. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sisyphus#Punishment_in_the_underworld), [TheFreeDictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Uphill+Battle).

Comment: @stafusa Read this: https://thetattooedbuddha.com/2018/03/31/what-to-do-when-its-an-uphill-battle/

Comment: @Lambie I did: A random blog post mentions both concepts together. That's no evidence the concepts are equivalent — also because, as I describe in my previous comment, they aren't. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Expressões que se valem de linguagem figurada, como essa, têm as mais diversas possibilidades de tradução, que costumam ser bem específicas para cada contexto.

Alguma possibilidades: **luta**/desafio/batalha (difícil); adversidades; situação/tarefa difícil, etc.; em que *difícil* pode ser substituído por *árduo*, *custoso*, *duro*, *penoso*, *complicado*, etc. Ou ainda expressões como **remar contra a maré**.

Exemplo:

- *You can still be approved. It'll be an uphill battle, but you can do it.*
  Você pode ainda passar de ano. Vai ser uma luta, mas você consegue.

O Linguee [oferece vários exemplos](https://www.linguee.com.br/ingles-portugues/traducao/an+uphill+battle.html) (não verificados) de traduções, e o English Experts tem um [ótimo texto](https://www.englishexperts.com.br/o-que-significa-a-expressao-uphill-battle/) com vários exemplos:

> A expressão em questão, uphill battle, é utilizada quando se quer falar de algo difícil e que requer muito esforço, por exemplo, chegar a algum lugar (obter sucesso), convencer alguém ou solucionar um problema. [...]
>
> Not easy; difficult to do, deal with, etc. [Merriam-Webster]
>       Very difficult; requiring a lot of effort. [Englishlessons.wordpress.com]
>
> It was an uphill battle, but we finally did it. [Foi uma luta (morro acima), mas nós finalmente conseguimos.]
>       It has been an uphill battle for her to get an education. [Tem sido uma batalha para ela conseguir se formar.]
>       Convincing the senator to see our point of view was an uphill battle, but we finally succeeded. [Convencer o senador a perceber o nosso ponto de vista foi complicado, mas finalmente conseguimos.]
>       It is an uphill battle to get the children to bed at night. [É uma verdadeira batalha fazer com que as crianças se deitem à noite.]
>       It was an uphill battle getting here. [Chegamos aqui aos trancos e barrancos.]
>       Resolving the problem was an uphill battle. [Resolvemos o problema aos trancos e barrancos.]
>       It will be an uphill battle, but I’m optimistic. [Vai ser uma luta dura, mas eu estou otimista.]

Comment: Good job, pal +1

Comment: Ótima resposta. Só p/ adicionar que, no contexto militar, encontro muito a expressão **Batalha Encarniçada** para indicar que o confronto foi particularmente difícil